# Can a java program be tested with Cucumber?

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber

I've been trying something new and I was curious whether a Java program can be tested with cucumber. I know cucumber can be used with Ruby etc but I've never tried it with Java.

I already installed the plugins I could find but I keep on getting :

```
Output of running [cmd, /C, cucumber, -r, C:\Users\XXX\CucumberTest\src\cucumber\features, C:\Users\XXX\CucumberTest\src\cucumber\features\myfeature.feature, -s] is:
--- START ---

'cucumber' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
--- END ---
```

Anybody got experience with Cucumber combined with Java or maybe knows why I get the message above?

Comment: http://cukes.info/install-cucumber-jvm.html

Comment: You may want to take a look at [Spock](http://docs.spockframework.org/en/latest/). It basically uses the same philosophy as Cucumber. It works with Groovy (which is very similar to Ruby), and it can test Java code.

Answer (score 2):

This has absolutely nothing to do with using Cucumber with Java. The error message you are getting is from the Windows command line and telling you that it couldn't find `cucumber` anywhere. Either you didn't install it, or you didn't put it in your `%PATH%`, or its extension is not in `%PATHEXT%`.

You would be getting the exact same error if you tried using it to test Ruby code. It isn't even found in the first place.